# Will lighttpd >1.4.45 run on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, lighttpd

I have an embedded system running 18.04 LTS with lighttpd 1.4.45.  There are features that have been added since 1.4.46 that I would like to use.  I have searched to see if anyone has had success running a later version on this OS, but I haven't found anything.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: by following the below method you will get lighttpd-1.4.46 which may have some security breaches, be careful.**

To compile LigHTTPd from source we need

1. Enable source code repositories from Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Get build dependencies of existing version

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep lighttpd
   sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
3. Get source of 1.4.46 version:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget https://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/releases-1.4.x/lighttpd-1.4.46.tar.gz
   tar -xf lighttpd-1.4.46.tar.gz
   cd lighttpd-1.4.46/
   ./configure
   make
   sudo checkinstall make install # to create deb
   ```
4. Check the version

   > ```
   > $ lighttpd -v  
   > lighttpd/1.4.46 - a light and fast webserver
   > ```

Comment: lighttpd 1.4.55 is the latest version of lighttpd as this time, released Jan 2020.  1.4.46 was released almost 2 1/2 years ago.  Please use the latest official release: lighttpd 1.4.55

Comment: @gstrauss this particular version was requested by the OP.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer above.  As to your comment, while I see that what was asked specified 1.4.46, I commented because the choice is short-sighted.  lighttpd 1.4.55 should be used instead of earlier versions because there have been *security* and other bug fixes in the *9 releases* and *565 commits* since lighttpd 1.4.46 was released 2 1/2 years ago.  To overlook the version discrepancy would be irresponsible.